# Random integer functions differences

Tags: javascript, random

inspecting some code, I found the following random integer generator function:

```
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return min ? min : min = 0,
        max ? max : max = 1,
        0 | Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
}
```

Comparing it with the equivalent function at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

I understand that the first creates and integer with `max` included, and that it checks for values or assign them defaults to `min` and `max` but I don't understand how it returns an integer and not a float without the `Math.floor()` method.

Is it achieved using `0 | Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min` expression? If so, how?

Comment: *Does* it return integers only?

Comment: Good one! Missed the OR.

Comment: My goodness, what awful code. An assignment as an operand to a conditional. \*holds nose\*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree. I was interested in the cryptic code, even if it lacks readability and adds nothing to a more expressive function like the one below, mainly because I never saw such code and I didn't know about the bitwise OR operator.

Comment: @caruso_g: Nothing wrong with the bitwise OR, or indeed with your curiousity. :-) It's some of the rest of that code that's awful (such as the example I pointed out). (I should underscore that I would never have made that comment if I thought it was *your* code, but it was clear it wasn't, so...)

Comment: @caruso_g: In fact, `((Math.random() * (max - min)) | 0) + min` would be a fairly standard version of `randomInt`, although on modern engines it's [a bit slower](http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-bitwise-or-for-flooring).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very nice thank you. So, each unit I add after the `|` operator, they will practically added to the flored integer at the left of the operator, correct? I have to admit I don't understand it why.
Btw, I had understood you got it that was not my code. ;)

Comment: @caruso_g: Not *added*, no. `4.3 | 4` is just `4`, for instance, not `8`. An individual bit's OR operation result is `1` if either of the operand bits is `1`, and `0` if not: `0 | 0` => `0`, `0 | 1` => `1`, `1 | 0` => `1`, `1 | 1` => `1`. The bitwise OR operator converts both of its operands to 32-bit integers, then does that for each of those 32 bits. In this case, it converts the left operand to an integer, which will have various bits set; converts the right operand (`0`), which has no bits set at all; and then does the OR, which means we end up with just the left operand's (floored) value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is converted to an integer with the `|` operator, which is the [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_Logical_Operators), the first step in computing the result is:

> The operands are converted to thirty-two-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeros and ones).

And because you're ORing with 0, this operation will not change the value of the result (other than the previously mentioned conversion).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, only why do you state that "this operation will not change the value of the result" even if it actually floor it to an integer from a float?

Comment: What I mean is, ORing with 0 won't change the bitwise result, as opposed to ORing with some other number, e.g. `1 |` would always give you an odd number.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It would be nice if you could add that clarification to the answer.

Comment: @caruso_g Already ahead of you. See my updated answer for more links and clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had already marked it as the answer in any case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`0 |` is a bitwise operation.
It has no effect on the value (ORing with zero returns the original value), but, like all bitwise operations, it truncates to an integer (bitwise operations make no sense on non-integers).

Comment: Well in js as you know it, it casts any value (Number or not) to a floored integer, any non number value will give 0.

Comment: Me either, although "it has no effect on the value" doesn't really make sense (it *does* have an effect: it floors it). But that doesn't make the answer not useful.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Did it originally state something different? If not don't see the reason either as states much the same as yours.

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't believe this answer was modified at all since it was first posted.